# Powershell script with automation account and managed identity Unauthorized when sending e-mail

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, azure-automation

I have been struggling with this script in Azure Automation to send a report to an e-mail but won't work. I have granted the required permission to the servicePrincipal but I get all the time `The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.` I even tried to connect with the scopes, but still the same. Then I tried to connect to AzAccount then get the AzAccessToken and then connect to graph using AccessToken but here I got an error

```
Connect-MgGraph : Cannot bind parameter 'AccessToken'. Cannot convert the "eyJ0
 value of type "System.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString". At line:5 char:30 + Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $token.Token +
```

I am getting the output of the variables `$inactiveUsers` and `$htmlReport` so the issue is with the e-mail

See the permissions:
[image]
What am I doing wrong ?

```
# Connect to Microsoft Graph
Connect-MgGraph -Identity

# inactive users with license(s)
$inactiveUsers = Get-MgUser -Filter 'accountEnabled eq false and assignedLicenses/$count ne 0' -ConsistencyLevel eventual -CountVariable licensedUserCount -All -Select UserPrincipalName,DisplayName

# Create a report variable
$userReport = @()

# Build the report
$htmlReport = "<html><body><h2>Disabled users with licenses report</h2><table border='1'><tr><th>User Principal Name</th><th>Display Name</th></tr>"

foreach ($user in $inactiveUsers) {
    $userPrincipalName = $user.UserPrincipalName
    $displayName = $user.DisplayName

    $htmlReport += "<tr><td>$userPrincipalName</td><td>$displayName</td></tr>"

    $userInfo = [PSCustomObject]@{
        UserPrincipalName = $userPrincipalName
        DisplayName = $displayName
    }

    $userReport += $userInfo
}

$htmlReport += "</table></body></html>"

# Send the email
$recipientEmail = "recipient@domain.com"
$subject = "Disabled users with licenses report"

# Construct the email
$emailMessage = @{
    "subject" = $subject
    "body" = @{
        "contentType" = "HTML"
        "content" = $htmlReport
    }
    "toRecipients" = @(@{ "emailAddress" = @{ "address" = $recipientEmail } })
}

# Convert to JSON
$emailJson = $emailMessage | ConvertTo-Json

# Send the email, this part is  not working and I don't know why...
$sendEmailUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/sender@domain.com/sendMail"
$sendEmailParams = @{
    "Uri" = $sendEmailUri
    "Method" = 'POST'
    "Body" = $emailJson
    "Headers" = @{
        "Content-Type" = "application/json"
    }
}

try {
    Invoke-RestMethod @sendEmailParams -ErrorAction Stop
    Write-Host "Email sent successfully."
} catch {
    Write-Error "Error sending email: $_"
}
```

Comment: Any reason you are using Invoke-RestMethod to send mail instead of Send-MgUserMail. When using Invoke-RestMethod, you are missing Authorization header and token

Comment: Error indicates the windows credentials you are using does not have the authentication to access the Route.  Your user login does not have the permission to access the route.  You need to change the server to allow the user access. Most systems moved from Window Credentials to OAUTH2.  OAUTH2 requires two steps.  Step one is to get the credentials.  Step 2 is perform query with the credentials.  So you may also need to switch from Windows Credentials to OAUTH2 credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error occurred as you are calling `Invoke-RestMethod` without passing access token as a secure string *(ConvertTo-SecureString $graphToken -AsPlainText -Force)* in **Authorization** header.

To resolve the error, you need to either pass access token as **secure string**
or use ***Send-MgUserMail*** as *@user2250152* suggested.

Initially, I granted below **permissions** to the automation account's service principal like this:

[image]

Now, I ran below ***modified*** script by replacing with `Send-MgUserMail` and got response:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Authentication
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Users
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Users.Actions

# Connect to Microsoft Graph
Connect-MgGraph -Identity

# inactive users with license(s)
$inactiveUsers = Get-MgUser -Filter 'accountEnabled eq false and assignedLicenses/$count ne 0' -ConsistencyLevel eventual -CountVariable licensedUserCount -All -Select UserPrincipalName,DisplayName

# Create a report variable
$userReport = @()

# Build the report
$htmlReport = "<html><body><h2>Disabled users with licenses report</h2><table border='1'><tr><th>User Principal Name</th><th>Display Name</th></tr>"

foreach ($user in $inactiveUsers) {
    $userPrincipalName = $user.UserPrincipalName
    $displayName = $user.DisplayName

    $htmlReport += "<tr><td>$userPrincipalName</td><td>$displayName</td></tr>"

    $userInfo = [PSCustomObject]@{
        UserPrincipalName = $userPrincipalName
        DisplayName = $displayName
    }

    $userReport += $userInfo
}

$htmlReport += "</table></body></html>"

# Send the email
$recipientEmail = "sridevi.maxxxxxxxx@gmail.com"
$subject = "Disabled users with licenses report"

# Construct the email message
$emailMessage = @{
    "Message" = @{
        "subject" = $subject
        "body" = @{
            "contentType" = "HTML"
            "content" = $htmlReport
        }
        "toRecipients" = @(@{ "emailAddress" = @{ "address" = $recipientEmail } })
    }
    "saveToSentItems" = $true 
}

# Convert to JSON with a higher depth limit
$emailJson = $emailMessage | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5

try {
    Send-MgUserMail -UserId "sri@xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com" -BodyParameter $emailJson 
    Write-Output "Email sent successfully."
}
catch {
    Write-Error "Error sending email: $_"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in user's **`Sent Items`** where mail sent successfully like this:

[image]